# Can not communicate with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration. update Firebase process and set valid options (API key, Project ID ..)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, native-android

E/Firebase-Installations: Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration. Please update your Firebase initialization process and set valid Firebase options (API key, Project ID, Application ID) when initializing Firebase.
E/FirebaseMessaging: Failed to get FIS auth token
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:5)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:8)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.setDefaultAttributesToBundle(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@23.0.0:10)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.startRpc(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@23.0.0:1)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.getToken(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@23.0.0:1)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.lambda$blockingGetToken$9$com-google-firebase-messaging-FirebaseMessaging(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@23.0.0:1)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.start(Unknown Source:6)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.RequestDeduplicator.getOrStartGetTokenRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@23.0.0:6)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@23.0.0:7)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.SyncTask.maybeRefreshToken(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@23.0.0:1)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.SyncTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@23.0.0:10)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:463)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:2)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException
at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doNetworkCallIfNecessary(FirebaseInstallations.java:417)
at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.lambda$doRegistrationOrRefresh$3$com-google-firebase-installations-FirebaseInstallations(FirebaseInstallations.java:375)
at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

I've cleared caches, changed API key from google cloud platform, updated google-services.json with latest keys. In main branch it didn't get this error but in specific branch. this issue comes.